# NumPy not importing in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: python, numpy, jenkins

I'm trying to run a Python script through Jenkins (On Linux), on a Windows agent. My code runs on both the Jenkins server and agent machine, but fails when running the Jenkins pipeline as numpy can't be loaded. I checked that mkl-service is installed.

Any ideas what it could be?

My Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
agent none
options {
    skipStagesAfterUnstable()
}
stages {
    stage('Build') {
    agent {
            docker {
                image 'python:2-alpine'
    }
    }
        steps {
            sh 'python -m py_compile test.py'
        }
    }
    stage('Deliver') {
        agent {label 'CI-W10-Box'}
        steps {
            bat 'conda env remove -y --name test'
            bat 'conda env create' // Build environment based on environment.yml
            bat 'conda activate test'
            bat 'c:\\Users\\Ross\\anaconda3\\envs\\test\\python -c "import numpy"'
        }
        post {
            success {
                sh 'ls dist/gh'
                archiveArtifacts 'dist/gh'
            }
            always {
                cleanWs()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I went with the simple command, `python -c "import numpy"` to isolate the problem and it doesn't load. The error message is:

```
C:\Users\Ross\workspace\test>c:\Users\Ross\anaconda3\envs\test\python -c "import numpy" 
c:\Users\Ross\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:138: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Ross\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "c:\Users\Ross\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "c:\Users\Ross\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.
```

Additionally, when I try `python -c "import mkl"`, I get `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _mklinit: The specified module could not be found.`. I'm wondering if there is a PATH variable that needs to be set or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to add the environment variable `CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE=1` like so:

```
stage('Deliver') {
            agent {label 'CI-W10-Box'}
            environment {
                CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE=1
            }
            steps {
                bat 'conda env remove -y --name test'
                bat 'conda env create' // Build environment based on environment.yml
                bat 'conda activate test'
                bat 'c:\\Users\\Ross\\anaconda3\\envs\\test\\Scripts\\pyinstaller --onefile gh-debug.spec'
                //bat 'c:\\Users\\Ross\\anaconda3\\envs\\test\\python -c "import mkl"'
            }
            post {
                success {
                    sh 'ls dist/gh'
                    archiveArtifacts 'dist/gh'
                }
                always {
                    cleanWs()
                }
            }
        }
```